# MFC Workspace Bar: "Failed to create empty document"

Tags: c++, mfc

I am attempting to create a dockable workspace bar much like the on in VS. I am using the BCGCBPro library and the function I am calling is essentially a control bar derived class.  In my CMainFrame::OnCreate function I am calling my create function responsable for creating a dockable workspace.

When I run the following, I get an assertion error:

```
if (!m_wndWorkSpace.Create (_T("Workspace"), this, CSize (200,200),
                            TRUE, ID_VIEW_WORKSPACE,
                            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_LEFT))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create workspace bar\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
```

The assertion error complains that my CObject* pOb pointer is null.

Now when i remove the WS_CHILD style, I get the infamous "Failed to create empty document":

```
if (!m_wndWorkSpace.Create (_T("Workspace"), this, CSize (200,200),
                            TRUE, ID_VIEW_WORKSPACE,
                            WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_LEFT))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create workspace bar\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
```

I've done a bunch of research, yet have no concrete ideas. I've tried some alternatives I've found on the internet yet nothing seems to be working. Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into the Debug Output. What are the last messages there?

Comment: Warning: Window creation failed: GetLastError returns 0x00000579
Failed to create workspace bar
Warning: Window creation failed: GetLastError returns 0x00000000
Warning: failed to create CFrameWnd.
Warning: CDocTemplate couldn't create a frame.

Comment: Those were the last lines when getting the "failed to create empty document" error. I believe it has to do with the resource file, is that a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You might have used rich edit control. To use rich edit controls, the common controls library has to be initialized.  Go into the InitInstance function in your main app and add AfxInitRichEdit(); and that should solve your problem.
[courtesy](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/CPP/Q_20582819.html)